# Transforming XML column data using SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis-2012

Looking for help on Transforming XML column data (Source : SQL DB) to row wise data in SQL Database.

I have a table with XML column in database. I want to extract this XML data, transform it, extract some of the nodes and store it row wise in another table SQL database. I believe SSIS has way to achieve this. can somebody guide to how to do this.

I have tried following steps and getting following error.

1. Created a package with Control flow task.
2. Added "Execute SQL Task" to extract the XML column data (First I am trying to fetch one XML value later want to loop for all the XML)
3. Connecting above input to Data flow task (with XML Source + OLE DB destination). I am trying to fetch the data from XML variable but I dont know how to define XSD path here.

Can somebody guide what I am following is the right way or is there is any better way to achieve this? BTW I am using SSIS 2012 version (visual studio 2010)

I tried google about this but I couldnt get the source as XML column data. (Every where XML data as file)

Answer (score 0):

Click on 'Generate XSD' below XSD path location. It will automatically generate the XSD for you

Comment: This type of answer should be in a comment.